# Do patterns not work with ansible-playbook and --limit?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory

I want to limit an ansible run to all webservers which are not in the windows group. I get this done when I create a new group:

```
[test]
webservers:!windows
```

and run it like this:

```
ansible-playbook -i inventories/staging/ site.yml --limit test
```

But when I try to avoid the group definition and put all into the limit statement it fails with *!windows event not found*

```
ansible-playbook -i inventories/staging/ site.yml --limit "webservers:!windows"
```

Is this not supported or do I something wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`!` is a special character in `bash` to expand previous commands.

You should use single quotes to avoid bash expansion: `--limit 'webservers:!windows'`