# Ansible: adhoc limit hosts

Tags: regex, ansible, ansible-inventory

I need to run the play limiting the host by odd or even. Play is running fine when I don't have any number in the group name, but when there is some number in the group name it's running for all hosts.

Here is the sample inventory file

```ini
[weblogic]
web_host[01:10]

[weblogic-oel7]
weblogic_host[01:10]
```

when I run the play for odd it's taking **all** hosts in the `weblogic-oel7` group since that host group name is ending with the number 7.

```bash
ansible all -i hosts.yml --limit '*01:*3:*5:*7:*9' --list
```

I'm unable to find a solution so modified the play to take the host as a variable and when I pass like below it's working fine.

```bash
ansible-playbook -i hosts sample.yml -e limit_host="{{ ansible_play_hosts[1::2] }}" --list-hosts
ansible-playbook -i hosts sample.yml -e limit_host="{{ ansible_play_hosts[::2] }}" --list-hosts
```

Is there any other better solution is there to do so? How can I ignore the group name when I use the limit flag and only take the hostnames?

We do have more than 1000 servers and more than 25 groups. The actual playbook takes the group names and then limits them with odd or even like below.

```bash
ansible-playbook playbooks/Patching/OSpatch.yml -i inventories/dev -l *0:*2:*4:*6:*8 -f 10
```

Playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: "{{ lookup('env','hostgroups') }} " 
  become: true
  become_user: root
  any_errors_fatal: false
  gather_facts: yes
```

Thanks

Comment: `ansible all -i hosts.yml --limit '*_host01:*_host3:*_host5:*_host7:*_host9' --list`, then?

Comment: can't do that since we have more than ~ 25 host groups and 1000 servers.

Comment: This should be part of your question, in an [edit], then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According [Patterns: targeting hosts and groups](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_patterns.html) it should be possible to apply a pattern

> *to choose which managed nodes or groups you want to execute against*

Even if there are some [limitations of patterns](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_patterns.html#limitations-of-patterns), it might be possible to use [advanced pattern options](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_patterns.html#advanced-pattern-options) in example [using regexes in patterns](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_patterns.html#using-regexes-in-patterns).

> *You can specify a pattern as a regular expression by starting the pattern with `~`*

Please take note that according [patterns and ad-hoc commands](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_patterns.html#patterns-and-ad-hoc-commands)

> *single quotes MUST be used to prevent bash interpolation.*

Regarding **your question:**

> *Is there any other better solution is there to do so? How can I ignore the group name when I use the limit flag and only take the hostnames?*

and based on your given sample inventory file `hosts.yml`, a playbook called with

```bash
ansible-playbook -i hosts.yml sample.yml --limit='~.*[\d]{1}(1|3|5|7|9)$'
```

would execute on

```
PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************
web_host01                 : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
web_host03                 : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
web_host05                 : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
web_host07                 : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
web_host09                 : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
weblogic_host01            : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
weblogic_host03            : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
weblogic_host05            : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
weblogic_host07            : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
weblogic_host09            : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

As you can see hosts of the group `weblogic-oel7` are catched but not all of them.

**Summary**

The pattern to catch odd numbers

```bash
--limit='~.*[\d]{1}(1|3|5|7|9)$'
```

and to catch even numbers

```bash
--limit='~.*[\d]{1}(0|2|4|6|8)$'
```

which can have a one leading digit but not a letter.

**Thanks to**

- [`ansible-playbook --limit` more than one host?](https://serverfault.com/a/1031372/448950)
- [Do patterns not work with `ansible-playbook` and `--limit`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47420327/6771046)
- [regex: Find one-digit number](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15099212/6771046)
- ... and have also a look into [regex to match only odd or even number](https://stackoverflow.com/a/691536/6771046) for
  `--limit='~.*\d[13579]$'`

---

**How to proceed further?**

Regarding

> *The actual playbook takes the group names and then limits them with odd or even ...*

you may have a look into [How to build your inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html), [hosts in multiple groups](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#hosts-in-multiple-groups) and [inheriting variable values: group variables for groups of groups](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#inheriting-variable-values-group-variables-for-groups-of-groups) since it might be possible to introduce

> *groups of groups using the `:children` suffix in INI or the `children:` entry in YAML.*

With this you create groups like `weblogic_odd` and `weblogic_even`. This approach is in example used to address infrastructure (and) locations.

---

**Further Documentation**

Can be found in the thread of Ansible Issue #[79822](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/79822) where an "*Incorrect behavior of regular expression in `ansible-playbook --limit` option*" is assumed but it turned out it is not. It is just

> *... constructing the host pattern, not selecting/excluding the hosts.*

in other words, the parameter `limit` and his regex capability is to define sets, but it is not mentioned as regex filter for hosts and as I understand from there.